# RaspBerry Pi Command Line/Application - List IP Devices

Tags: java, linux, networking, ip, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to make a very simple Raspberry Pi application that would auto-update with all the IP addresses, Mac addresses, and their respective device names that are all on the same network. I have absolutely no idea where to start, any recommendations on how to get this done?

I play to connect a LCD and mount it next to my router so I have easy access to all the devices that are connected to my network.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you chosen a programming language to work with?

Comment: I can do Java, I've worked with it for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about "arp-scan" command?

```
$ sudo apt-get install arp-scan
$ sudo arp-scan -l --interface wlan0
Interface: wlan0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
192.168.0.211   14:da:e9:XX:YY:ZZ       (Unknown)
192.168.0.1     1c:b1:7f:XX:YY:ZZ       (Unknown)
192.168.0.201   1c:ba:8c:XX:YY:ZZ       (Unknown)
192.168.0.202   e8:9d:87:XX:YY:ZZ       Toshiba
192.168.0.203   00:25:dc:XX:YY:ZZ       Sumitomo Electric Networks, Inc
192.168.0.210   fc:c2:de:XX:YY:ZZ       (Unknown)
192.168.0.212   64:bc:0c:XX:YY:ZZ       (Unknown)
192.168.0.207   10:6f:3f:XX:YY:ZZ       (Unknown)
192.168.0.208   90:a2:da:XX:YY:ZZ       GHEO SA
192.168.0.205   48:5d:60:XX:YY:ZZ       Azurewave Technologies, Inc.
192.168.0.210   fc:c2:de:XX:YY:ZZ       (Unknown) (DUP: 2)

12 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.8.1: 256 hosts scanned in 5.247 seconds (48.79 hosts/sec). 11 responded
```

Your interface might be eth0 instead of wlan0.

(Added)
Because the arp-scan package contains an old vendor list file, many devices fail to get their name (represented as "(Unknown)").
To correct that:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/royhills/arp-scan.git
$ sudo cp /usr/share/arp-scan/ieee-oui.txt{,.org}
$ sudo cp arp-scan/ieee-oui.txt /usr/share/arp-scan/
```

After refreshing the file, we can get the output like the following:

```
$ sudo arp-scan -l --interface wlan0
Interface: wlan0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
192.168.0.211   14:da:e9:XX:YY:ZZ       ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.
192.168.0.1     1c:b1:7f:XX:YY:ZZ       NEC Platforms, Ltd.
192.168.0.201   1c:ba:8c:XX:YY:ZZ       Texas Instruments
192.168.0.202   e8:9d:87:XX:YY:ZZ       Toshiba
192.168.0.203   00:25:dc:XX:YY:ZZ       Sumitomo Electric Industries,Ltd
192.168.0.205   48:5d:60:XX:YY:ZZ       AzureWave Technology Inc.
192.168.0.210   fc:c2:de:XX:YY:ZZ       Murata Manufacturing Co., Ltd.
192.168.0.212   64:bc:0c:XX:YY:ZZ       LG Electronics
192.168.0.208   90:a2:da:XX:YY:ZZ       GHEO SA
192.168.0.207   10:6f:3f:XX:YY:ZZ       BUFFALO.INC

11 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.8.1: 256 hosts scanned in 5.750 seconds (44.52 hosts/sec). 10 responded
```

All devices correctly got their (vendor) name.